# Long iPhone App name to be displayed on multiple lines

Tags: iphone, ios4

My App name is 17 characters long. When installed on a device it looks like App...Name. Is there any way to display app names on multiple lines?
Please help.

Comment: Multi line name is not supported. The name is middle truncated after some width of the name.. Try shortening your app name

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, You can't. I think the iPad supports 15 characters to display the app name in full and iPhone supports 14 characters ... retina display on iPhone did support 15 characters. try Shortening ur app name if u want to display in full.

EDIT:  It Depends on the width of the characters, not on no of characters. Like if you use iiiii....... u can have more characters ...Thanks to inder kumar Rathore

Comment: @Tornado.. It's not about the number of characters it's about the width of the string. e.g you can name your app as "iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii" as the width of 'i' character is less thus name can adjust more characters.

Comment: oh i forgot about it You are absolutely right @InderKumarRathore

Comment: @InderKumarRathore i think previous ios versions like ios 3.1.3 can have a limited number of characters ... need to check out ...any ways now it width that really matters.

Comment: but I saw there are many apps with their names written on two lines

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible. You can have a shorter name for the home screen and a longer name on the app store, you just enter the longer one when submitting your app (for example, Super Crate Box appears as SCB on the home screen).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple line Name are not supported, it has limit of 15 character even if character are long then limit may decrease, may it will not take 15 charter. it is depends on size of character

Comment: yeah it is mostly between 12 to 14 chars