# xamarin forms app icon text has no spaces on ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I have a cross platform Xamarin Forms app which has the same app name in both the android manifest and the ios info.plist.

On android the name appears correctly under the app icon, however on ios there are no spaces between the words, so what would appear as "My Test App" on android appears as "MyTestApp" on ios.

I have seen this before on other apps, where the name has spaces and appears multi-line, so I guess it's figuring out how to get the app name multi-line.

Is there any other place to set this rather than the plist file?

UPDATE:

Just read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765783/long-iphone-app-name-to-be-displayed-on-multiple-lines) which states multi-line app names are not supported, but it's from 2012, so is this still the case?

Comment: You're absolutely correct! Depending on the characters used, you can generally only display 11 to 16 characters on a single line. Spaces will be trimmed first, then the name will be truncated to end in an ellipsis.

Comment: "My Test App" can be shown as an application name on iOS. But if your name is larger, it will be truncated to "MyTestAppss..." and spaces will be omitted. How do you set the name in info.plist?

Answer (score 5):

To show spaces in your app name, you need to put `&#x2007;` where you want the spaces to be. That will then be read as a space character by the compiler/iOS OS.

Note: You need to do this in the **source** of your *info.plist* file. It won't work if you use the project settings layout. Look for the **CFBundleDisplayName** tag.